# When pressing cmd+s the "s" is entered as typo

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, save

I am using Mac-book pro(osx). When I try to save the source code in VSCode IDE, the typo of "s" when pressing cmd+s appears frequently. This only seem to happen in VSCode. Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: You are maybe hitting the s-key a fraction of a second before the cmd key. I do that a lot. Hit the cmd key and then hit the s key.

Comment: This can be self answering, but I found a way to solve this problem by adjusting "delay until repeat" option.
Please refer to the explanation in this link. https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25116?locale=ko_KR&viewlocale=en_US